# Style dropdownlist i MVC

Tags: c#, css, dropdownlistfor

How do i go about to style each selectlistitem in my dropdownlist?
Can I give each item an id and access the in css?
Im trying to change the background-color of each item...

Here is the code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BehanlingsColour, new SelectList(
                  new List<Object>{ 
                       new { value = 0 , text = "Red" },
                       new { value = 1 , text = "Blue" },
                       new { value = 2 , text = "Green"},

                    },
                  "value",
                  "text",
                   2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Html.DropDownListFor renders a , so I don't know why you're saying you're not using  tags.

CSS does not care about server-side code, only rendered HTML, so if you're having issues then always show us the rendered HTML and your CSS.

Anyway, to style your  element (and remember that because  is a "replaced element" in CSS the opportunities for styling are limited, but you can do some cool things: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

You can override the id="" attribute of the  so you can use the element selector in CSS, like so:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BehanlingsColour, new SelectList(
                      new List<Object>{ 
                           new { value = 0 , text = "Red" },
                           new { value = 1 , text = "Blue" },
                           new { value = 2 , text = "Green"},

                        },
                      "value",
                      "text",
                       2), new { id = "mySelect" })


        #mySelect { width: 135px; }
//or
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BehanlingsColour, new SelectList(
                      new List<Object>{ 
                           new { value = 0 , text = "Red" },
                           new { value = 1 , text = "Blue" },
                           new { value = 2 , text = "Green"},

                        },
                      "value",
                      "text",
                       2), new { class = "dropdown" })
```

However if you're using this DropDownListFor in a partial view then the id="" attribute won't be unique in the document, which is illegal. Try using different selectors that make use of the context, such as the descendant selector.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud be able to use css pseudo-selectors, such as:

```
option:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
```